# Conditional: IF current author's custom post has a post thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, conditional-content

I'm trying to make a conditional if the current author has uploaded a featured image in a custom post, but it ain't workin' ...

```
<?php if ( 
1 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTPOSTTYPE" ) 
&& is_user_logged_in() 
&& has_post_thumbnail()
) { ?>
```

Comment: You mean if the post has a featured image no matter who upload it right? The has_post_thumbnail function just checks if the post has a feature image, not if the current author upload it.

Comment: if the current logged in author/user has published a custom post with a featured imaged attached to their post

Comment: Also I believe that your logic is wrong based on what you said you are trying to do. count_user_posts returns the number of posts the author posted. So you are saying if the user has posted one post (no matter which post) and if is logged in and if the post has a thumbnail.

Comment: It works for me so far... i'm just trying to add the featured image condition on top of what works

Comment: Working do not imply correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
if ( 
1 < count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTPOSTTYPE" ) 
&& is_user_logged_in() 
&& has_post_thumbnail()
) {
?>
```

// `if(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)`

to debug, you should check the output of the following...

```
var_dump(count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTPOSTTYPE" ));
var_dump(is_user_logged_in());
var_dump(has_post_thumbnail());
```

Comment: What is that? I want it to equal 1 post. Please check your answer's code.

Comment: Then use `1 ===` operator not `1==`

Comment: how is your code different to what I showed in my question?

Comment: It is different at `1<count...` as `1== True` is equal to `1==1`...

Answer (score 0):

The condition in my answer says that if the user is logged in and if the current user is the user that posted the current post and if that post has a featured image then do something.

```
if(is_user_logged_in() 
&& get_current_user_id() === get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )
&& has_post_thumbnail()) {
    /* action */
}
```

Comment: I don't want the current post, I want the current user's custom post. This conditional needs to work in any theme file, as mine does now.

Comment: What do you mean by user's custom post?

Comment: The custom post that the current author published. Trust me it works.

Comment: The code above works for custom posts. You are in a single custom post page right? When you check with count_user_posts you just check how many post the user has posted it. So if the user has posted more than one your condition will fail. That's why Vishal put a greater condition, to catch that scenario. Sorry if I insist but I am trying to help.

Comment: My original code worked in any template file to restrict the current logged in user accordingly, it didn't only apply the condition when it was on a specific cpt page or otherwise. Thanks for helping and hanging in there ;)

Comment: Unless you provide an ID or a WP_Post object has_post_thumbnail check the global variable $post which changes in every page/post the user is currently visiting. Because my English are not that good let's clarify again what you want to do. As far I understand you want to check if the current user has published a post of a certain custom post type and if that post has a featured image. Do you want to check if the current user has published a post with a certain custom post type without care about which post it is and then which post you want to check for a feature image? Anyone?

Comment: "As far I understand to check if the current user has published a post of a certain custom post type and if that post has a featured image" - Yes, that's correct - but, the custom post must be the same one that also has the featured image. Each author will only be publishing 1 post anyway.

Comment: Sorry but I can't think a way to do it in every template file other than in a single custom post template file or in a custom loop / wp_query. You have to know which post the current user is visiting before checking. Checking all post the user published is to much of an overhead.